# php - keep value that is shuffled even if page is refreshed

Tags: php

I made a quiz that generates a random answer at the end by using the `shuffle()` function.
I want it to stay on the same answer and not to shuffle again.

My code:

```
<?php

//Array of cars
$answer = array(
"Mercedes", 
"Benz", 
"Honda", 
"Toyota", 
"Nissan", 
"Mazda", 
"Hyundai", 
"Ford", 
"Lexus", 
"Lamborghini", 
"Ferrari", 
"Porche", 
"Mitsubushi", 
"Scion", 
"Chrysler", 
"Jeep", 
"Masarati"
);

// Shuffle the order
shuffle($answer);

echo $answer[0];
?>
```

> For example: if `$answer` was shuffled and generated "Mitsubushi" ---
>   when I refresh the page it should stay "Mitsubushi" but what happens
>   is that when the page is refreshed it reshuffles again.
>
> So when I refresh the page, it `echo`'s another thing do the `shuffle()` function.

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Store the result in a `$_SESSION[]` variable and only shuffle if that variable's not set.

Comment: @MikeW don't I need to set cookies for that?

Comment: PHP should handle that for you.

Answer (score 2):

Store the array into a session variable

```
    <?php
    session_start();

    //Array of cars
    $answer = array(
    "Mercedes", 
    "Benz", 
    "Honda", 
    "Toyota", 
    "Nissan", 
    "Mazda", 
    "Hyundai", 
    "Ford", 
    "Lexus", 
    "Lamborghini", 
    "Ferrari", 
    "Porche", 
    "Mitsubushi", 
    "Scion", 
    "Chrysler", 
    "Jeep", 
    "Masarati"
    );

    // Shuffle the order only first time
   if(!isset($_SESSION['shuffle_answer'])){
      $_SESSION['shuffle_answer']=shuffle($answer);
   }

    if(isset($_SESSION['shuffle_answer'])){
       echo $_SESSION['shuffle_answer'][0];
    }else{
       echo $answer[0];
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Didn't work, everytime I refresh the page, returns a different value because it's being shuffled over and over again.

Comment: If its OK with unset stay with that code ... or if you want to keep the first shuffle use the updated code and use unset($_SESSION['shuffle_answer']) when you needed...

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for [sessions](http://php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php).  You need to call `session_start` and store the value in `$_SESSION`.

Answer (score 0):

you can try "unset" the variable $answer[0] before the "echo"

// Shuffle the order
shuffle($answer);

echo $answer[0];
unset($answer[0])