# How to apply php user session to random quote snippet?

Tags: php, session, echo, session-cookies, shuffle

Still learning `PHP` and trying to apply a user session snippet to my quote snippet so that it doesn't shuffle on every user page re-load.

Here is the working session code being applied to a different random quote snippet: [php - keep value that is shuffled even if page is refreshed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24857267/php-keep-value-that-is-shuffled-even-if-page-is-refreshed)

How do I properly apply the session code from the above URL answer to my `PHP` quote code here? Spent 2 hours now trying to apply the session code in the above link to this snippet but just cant get it right!

```
<?php 
$r_array=file('quotes.txt'); 
shuffle($r_array); 
echo $mQuotePath[0]; 
echo $r_array[0]; 
?>
```

I also checked out the `PHP` session tutorial [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php) but I am still lost. Would someone be so kind in showing me how this is done? Thanks so much!

Comment: not completely sure what you are asking but .. you could on load check a session variable for a quote, if its there display it, otherwise pick one from the file, display that and put it in the session variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
<?php 
session_start();

if(!isset($_SESSION['shuffled_array'])){
    $_SESSION['shuffled_array'] = shuffle(file('quotes.txt')); 
}
$r_array=$_SESSION['shuffled_array']; 
// echo $mQuotePath[0]; // Not sure where you're getting this variable from but it doesn't seem to be declared
echo $r_array[0]; 
?>
```

Comment: probably don't want the whole file in the array, just the one random quote

Comment: @tim I believe that wasn't the stated logic limitation. The only constraint was that "...it doesn't shuffle on every user page re-load". But yes, if you don't want/need to store the entire array, you can just store the one value.

Comment: rather inefficient to store a copy of that whole file for each person, if you want each person to have a particular shuffled version, store the array keys(line numbers) in the session, not the whole file

Comment: @tim True, that is more memory efficient, but then you have to load the array from file on every page load to get the corresponding value which is less IO efficient. Depends on your system, contents of the file and your priorities.

Comment: well, one day the OP will bother coming back and we might learn what they actually want ;)

Comment: PERFECT!! EXACTLY!! Ohhh so that's what I needed to do.... seems I had a couple extra unneeded lines as well. Thank you so much for showing me the proper way to do this!

Comment: Would it be possible to have all this code in a `php` file and call something smaller like `<?php echo $quote; ?>` after including the `php` file of course? What would I need to change/add to make that happen? Thanks again!

Comment: @Kita Did you check the code? It displays nothing when executed on a webpage. It doesnt seem to be working...